# Idiomatic way to join a vector to either a plain keyword or a vector of keywords

Tags: vector, clojure, keyword

Looking for simplest or most idiomatic way to deal with input that may either be a simple keyword or a vector of keywords.  Perhaps a function that converts a plain keyword to a list.  Trying to avoid an if clause, and also trying to avoid too much function chaining.

```
 (defn togethr [v1]
   (into [] (flatten (into [:a] (vector v1))))

 (togethr :b) 
 ; => [:a :b]

 (togethr [:b :c])
 ; => [:a :b :c]
```

Here I'm chaining 4 function calls and I suspect there is an easier (more idiomatic) way.

Comment: Arthur’s answer is a good one, but stepping back to the wider context, having a parameter which may be a keyword, or a collection of keywords is often an antipattern. It may be better to change the calling code to pass a vector keywords consistently. Stuart Sierra has even coined a term for this: [‘heisenparameter’](http://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/10/clojure-donts-heisenparameter).

Comment: This is what I was looking for without being able to articulate it.  Although, Arthur, did answer my question, and I highly appreciate him taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate you taking a step back and guiding me down a better path than just straight-up giving me what I asked for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arthur’s answer is a good one, but stepping back to the wider context, having a parameter which may be a keyword, or a collection of keywords is often an antipattern. It may be better to change the calling code to pass a vector of keywords consistently. Stuart Sierra has even coined a term for this: [‘heisenparameter’](http://stuartsierra.com/2015/06/10/clojure-donts-heisenparameter).

Answer (score 2):

it's not at all unusual to use an if in cases like this. It gets it down to one function call and one if expression:

```
user> (defn togethr [thing]
        (into [:a] (if (sequential? thing) thing [thing])))
#'user/togethr
user> (togethr 1)
[:a 1]
user> (togethr :b)
[:a :b]
user> (togethr [:b :c])
[:a :b :c]
```